# GEKKO optimization for each datapoint in the csv

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, pyomo, gekko

So I have an objective function in the format

`3*[var_1] + [ROW_MEAN_hpbh]*[var_2] + [MAX_feia] * [var_3]`

where

```
[ROW_MEAN_hbph] is the row mean of 2 columns
```

```
[MAX_feia] is the max value of another column of the dataset


[var_1] [var_2] [var_3] are varibales with upper bound and lower bound defined
```

I need an expression parser where it can read the variables

Answer (score 0):

The question needs some additional clarification, but here is an example script that possibly meets the objectives of the question. Please clarify, if needed.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO

# Example dataset
data = {
    'col1': [1, 2, 3],
    'col2': [4, 5, 6],
    'col_feia': [7, 8, 9]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Calculate ROW_MEAN_hbph and MAX_feia
ROW_MEAN_hbph = df[['col1', 'col2']].mean(axis=1).mean()
MAX_feia = df['col_feia'].max()

# Gekko model
m = GEKKO()
var_1,var_2,var_3 = m.Array(m.Var,3,lb=1,ub=5)
m.Minimize(3*var_1 + ROW_MEAN_hbph*var_2 + MAX_feia*var_3)
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=True)
print('var_1:', var_1.value[0])
print('var_2:', var_2.value[0])
print('var_3:', var_3.value[0])
```

The solution is the lower bound for all variables, but this may change if you update with your own data.

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
    1  1.55000E+01  0.00000E+00
 Successful solution

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  0.018999999999999996 sec
 Objective      :  15.5
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------

var_1: 1.0
var_2: 1.0
var_3: 1.0
```

If you need to have the equations applied to each row of the data, then switch to parameter regression mode with `m.options.IMODE=2`.